# SPARK : failure: ``union'' expected but `(' found

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe called df with column named employee_id. I am doing:

```
 df.registerTempTable("d_f")
val query = """SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY employee_id) row_number FROM d_f"""
val result = Spark.getSqlContext().sql(query)
```

But getting following issue. Any help?

```
[1.29] failure: ``union'' expected but `(' found
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY employee_id) row_number FROM d_f
                            ^
java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.29] failure: ``union'' expected but `(' found
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY employee_id) row_number FROM d_f
```

Comment: does the query work if run directly in Db?

Comment: `SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY employee_id) row_number FROM d_f as t`

Comment: Query is fine. You are getting error in some other part and not here. Post the complete query.

Comment: @Praveen, how aliasing the table would a solution here?

Comment: @Praveen, I haven't tested but logically it shouldn't be the case. Since the query involves only one table aliasing is not necessary at all; in other words in no way DB engine would get ambiguity about the references.

Answer (score 17):

**Spark 2.0+**

Spark 2.0 introduces native implementation of window functions ([SPARK-8641](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8641)) so `HiveContext` should be no longer required. Nevertheless similar errors, not related to window functions, can be still attributed to the differences between SQL parsers.

**Spark <= 1.6**

Window functions have been introduced in Spark 1.4.0 and require [`HiveContext`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext) to work. [`SQLContext`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext) won't work here.

Be sure you you use Spark >= 1.4.0 and create the `HiveContext`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
```

Comment: `sc` is SparkContext.

Comment: But why do window functions need a HiveContext? What is the difference between HiveContext and SQLContext?

Comment: @DanielDarabos In this particular case it is simply about the support for Hive UDAFs. All window functions in Spark < 2.0.0 are expressed using Hive UDAF, hence cannot work without HiveContext.

Comment: I see, thanks! Thanks for updating the answer too. I've added a link to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8641.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is true,

I am using spark version 1.6.0 and there you need a HiveContext to implement 'dense_rank' method.

From Spark 2.0.0 on words there will be no more 'dense_rank' method.

So for Spark 1.4,1.6 <2.0 you should apply like this.

table hive_employees having three fields :: 
                                          place : String,
                                          name : String,
                                          salary : Int

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("denseRank test")//.setMaster("local")

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val hqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

val result = hqlContext.sql("select empid,empname, dense_rank() over(partition by empsalary order by empname) as rank from hive_employees")

result.show()