# does spark support all sql syntax

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COL1 ORDER BY COL2)` in my pyspark script, but running with error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.26] failure: ``union'' expected but `('
>   found SELECT *, MAX(cctry) OVER(PARTITION by ei) maxcc from tmp1

does spark support PARTITION keyword?

Comment: Show us your whole query

Comment: Thanks, i found the right answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786912/spark-failure-union-expected-but-found