# Spark sql top n per group

Tags: apache-spark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, top-n

How can I get the top-n (lets say top 10 or top 3) per group in `spark-sql`?

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/ provides a tutorial for general SQL. However, spark does not implement subqueries in the where clause.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the window function feature that was added in Spark 1.4
Suppose that we have a productRevenue table as shown below.
[image]

the answer to **What are the best-selling and the second best-selling products in every category** is as follows

```
SELECT product,category,revenue FROM 
   (SELECT product,category,revenue,dense_rank() 
         OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY revenue DESC) as rank 
    FROM productRevenue) tmp 
WHERE rank <= 2
```

Tis will give you the desired result

Comment: This works great in scala. However as SQL strings this fails with a strange error as described here https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/3dff11860ae042792cea6970447c4592  failure: ``union'' expected but `(' found

Comment: Solution is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786912/spark-failure-union-expected-but-found