# Getting first n elements in Spark group?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**Why this is not [Spark sql top n per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660625/spark-sql-top-n-per-group)**:

I myself thought this was a duplicate, just now. But it isn't afterall. The difference is: I additionally need to make an aggregation beforehand. I edit my question below accordingly. So I need to have `totalScore` as the sum of all `score`s, the `score`s are used for sorting within a group and then dismissed. Only the `code` of the top ranked elements per grouped, shall enter the list, but the `totalScore` shall be made up from all the `score`s. So we cannot dismiss some elements per group and then later aggregate. We need to first aggregate and keep all elements and afterwards get rid of some. Now this could be done by splitting the original DataFrame in two do each thing separately and then join. But that does not sound very efficient.

---

I hava a Spark `DataFrame` that I with dem Schema

```
root
 |-- inputRowID: long (nullable = false)
 |-- score: double (nullable = true)
 |-- code: string (nullable = true)
```

and I want to do

```
val outDF = inDF.
  sort($"inputRowID", $"score".desc).
  groupBy("inputRowID").
  agg(
    sum($"score").as("totalScore"),
    collect_list($"code").as("list"))
```

getting `outDF` with the Schema

```
root
 |-- inputRowID: long (nullable = false)
 |-- totalScore: long (nullable = false)
 |-- list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Now I want only the first `n` elements in the array to be kept. So I have been trying something like

```
outDF.
  map(r => Row(r(0), r(1).take(n)) )
```

(which of course does not work). Alternatively I thought about taking the frist `n` elements from the group, something like

```
val outDF = inDF.
  sort($"inputRowID", $"sorter".desc).
  groupBy("inputRowID").
  agg(take(n)).
  agg(
    collect_list($"code").as("list"))
```

but there is not function for that as far as I can see. Any ideas?

Comment: you can write your own user-defined function (UDF) and those those on rows.

Comment: And applying `flatmap` on each group doesn't work as well?

Comment: @AKSW: Can you post the code? I am not sure how to do it - I have been trying for a while now.

Comment: please share example data and expected output